# Android apps doesn't receive FCM notification from my app server

Tags: php, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

My Android apps can receive FCM from Firebase console just fine, however not from my app server.

Here's my snippet of my php script.

```
$target = 'device code';
$data = array('message' => 'Hello','title'=>'FCM Push Notifications');

function sendFCMMessage($data,$target){
   //FCM API end-point
   $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
   $server_key = 'server key';      

   $fields = array();
   $fields['data'] = $data;
   $fields['priority'] = 'high';
   if(is_array($target)){
    $fields['registration_ids'] = $target;
   }else{
    $fields['to'] = $target;
   }
   //header with content_type api key
   $headers = array(
    'Content-Type:application/json',
        'Authorization:key='.$server_key
   );
   //CURL request to route notification to FCM connection server (provided by Google)           
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
   $result = curl_exec($ch);
   if ($result === FALSE) {
    die('Oops! FCM Send Error: ' . curl_error($ch));
   }
   curl_close($ch);
   return $result;
}

$pn = sendFCMMessage($data,$target);
echo $pn;
```

but I did received the success response after run my script like this one below.

```
{
   "multicast_id":4696016312851064849,
   "success":1,
   "failure":0,
   "canonical_ids":0,
   "results":[
      {
         "message_id":"0:1486632797062481%1749d09ff9fd7ecd"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: add PHP flag, since most people use other languages for developing android. i don't know how it works but maybe a Log should help others understand what's wrong and give you solution.

Comment: Hi. When sending messages from the Firebase Console, it will be treated as a `notification` payload. In your PHP Script, you are only sending a `data`-only message payload. See the difference of two [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages). It is possible that you only handle `notification` messages in your client app. Can you post your Android side code?

Comment: @AL. Thank you ! I overlook that part. I found my answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my working code change you php code similar to this but change parameter

```
$apiKey = "fjdfhdjskajklsjdsalkdsajkldsakdjksadjksadsa-";       
                        
foreach($data as $deviceid)
{
    $arydevice[] = $deviceid->gcmregid;
}
                    
// print_r($arydevice);
$count = count($arydevice);
                
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) 
{
    $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
                
    $fields = array('to'=>(string)$arydevice[$i] ,'notification'=>array('title'=>'title','body'=>"1",'click_action'=>'click action','icon'=>'ic_stat_final','sound'=>'default','color'=>'#00aff0'),'data'=>array('multicast_id'=>$mid,'success'='0','schoolid'=>$SchoolId,'timestamp'=>$timestamp,'title'=>$title));
        
    $headers = array(
                        'Authorization: key=' . $apiKey,
                        'Content-Type: application/json'
                    );      

    // print_r($fields);
    // print_r($headers);
    // die;
                
    // var_dump($payload);

    // Open connection
    $ch = curl_init();          

    // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);    
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE,CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ));
                    
    // Execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
                    
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

Comment: first device id should be string andjson data whatever you want you have to sent as key value pair in data fieald

Comment: => change in this cose in fields object i m using yii framework